# Deleting inbox email in gmail results in delete of reply

Tags: email, gmail, webmail

When I do a reply and hit send in gmail, I sometimes will subsequently hit delete to delete the present email. But I have found that gmail will then subsequently delete the reply email in the Sent folder.

Which has me wondering:

- Did the reply get sent out?
- Can this behaviour be modified? Like, can the sent message be retained in Sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that gmail is linking the two messages in a conversation.

To only delete one of the messages you will have to:

1. Select the conversation
2. Open the message you want to delete.
3. Click the three vertical dots on the right hand side of the message.
4. Select "delete this message".

You will then see a popup at the bottom of the screen telling you the message has been moved to trash. The message you want to keep should be un-impacted.